# Add/Remove dynamically UIViews from a Storyboard's UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm new to IOS programming so I apologize if my question is obvious.

I created a UIViewController in storyboard, which contains a UIScrollView and multiple subviews.

These subviews (most often UITextViews) are filled with content from an external API, and content can thus be nil : in this case I would need to remove that subview which is empty.

For now I set this view as an IBOutlet and in **viewDidLoad**, if content is nil, I call

```
[self.thatView removeFromSuperView];
```

1. Is there a more efficient way to do that, for instance in **loadView**, in order to prevent that view to even load?
2. Is the usual method to handle subviews **layoutSubviews**?

Thx for your help

Comment: Are you getting the response from External API in a JSON format ?

Comment: yes everything is in JSON format

Comment: So instead of removing it after creating it... its better that you dont create those views whose values are not available...

Comment: and how do you programmatically avoid to create that subview which is an outlet in the storyboard?

Comment: Instead of creating the views using the OUTLET use the programmatic approach to create view in the parent view

Comment: It has to be of a dynamic nature instead of the static one. If you are going to create it and then remove it later on then there might be some effect on the app performance.

Comment: so no way to handle dynamic UIView loading with storyboard?

Comment: You can but this will on contrary affect the performance as you have to overrider the load view method which is not suggested till you are doing some real custom stuff over there.

Answer (score 0):

Any call before viewDidLoad will cause you problems unfortunately, you need to finish the load of a view before you dismiss it.